# Elixir and Docker

Tags: docker, elixir

I have a freshly generated Phoenix app and I'm trying to Dockerize it.

I'm running into the following issue:
If I boot Phoenix locally (`mix phx.server`) it works fine (connects to localhost PG)
If I run it in PROD (`MIX_ENV=prod mix phx.server`) it connects to RDS

If I run in Docker / dev mode (`docker-compose up`) I get this connection error[image]

If I run in Docker / prod mode I get the same error

I figure Docker not connecting locally is due to some networking issue (localhost vs docker host), but it still looks for localhost when running in prod.

Tried:

```
`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up`
`MIX_ENV=prod docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up`
```

I’ve tried Phoenix 1.3 and the latest RCs with no luck.

Elixir does ask for a `DATABASE_URL` on top of the normal prod.secret.exs DB config

I even tried putting a PG container into the compose setup and linked it. Elixir still asks for Localhost.

No DATABASE_URL in my env.

I’ve tried umbrella apps all the way to vanilla Phoenix. No love at all.

I have exported PORT (as Elixir wants that)

Answer (score 3):

You have to tell Pheonix which host to access your database on.  That is not `localhost` inside the container- Postgres is running in a different container.  From your screenshot looks like you named your db container `postgres` which means you can hit your db at `http://postgres` from inside your Phoenix container.  Update your connection details for local to use `postgres` or set the `DATABASE_URL=postgres` as an environment variable in your docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: I have setup prod.secret.exs to point to AWS RDS in prod with no luck; also linking directly to a PG container.

Comment: Accepting as DATABASE_URL in docker-compose.yml did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> If I run in Docker / dev mode (docker-compose up) I get this connection error

`mix phx.server` will use dev config as default, so which means if you run the image with dev mode, it will use the dev config, the DB hostname will be `localhost`.

> If I run in Docker / prod mode I get the same error

Usually, phoenix generates the `prod.secret.exs` does not have `hostname`, you need to add it manually. If you run it against `docker-compose`, the `hostname` should be the database service name you specified in your `docker-compose.yml`

> No DATABASE_URL in my env.

If you try to use `DATABASE_URL` format configuration, you need to add this environment variable into your docker-compose.yml backend service configuration. In general, if you use `distillery`, you can add `REPLACE_OS_VARS` in your `rel/config.exs`, then you can use the environment variable like: `${DATABASE_URL}`.

1. *`REPLACE_OS_VARS` only works with strings*
2. *you can refer this [repository](https://github.com/sgyyz/dockerize_elixir) to try it out.*